# Download/Export installed Packages on Ubuntu Server (local, without repo)

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, source-packages

i'm trying to save the installed Packages on my Ubuntu Server in order to add them to a repository.
I can download the installed packages with apt-get download  but this will attempt to download the packages from the official repositories.

Is it possible to export/save the installed packages without redownloading them from an official repo?
I've seen some solutions with --upgrade --no-download but they do not really for work for me.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I don't want to download the same packages over and over again from an online resource.

Comment: Why would you they get updated on a regular basis.

Comment: If you haven't cleared the cache, you can get the deb files from `/var/cache/apt/archives` (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1016/158442). The use the other answers to set up a repo with those deb files.

Comment: @muru How did i not come accross this. I think this will be the solution. Thanks alot!